# Using IF to evaluate an specific string

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google sheet job planning project and I want to move a row of data to another sheet but only if the job was done by me. I did something like

```
if(s.getName() == "Job Planning" && r.getColumn() == 4 && r.getValue() == "Complete and Sent") {
   var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Complete and Sent");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 2, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
}
```

the problem is that I can't do something like --

```
if(name.getValue() == "Miguel") {
}
```

As there is more that 1 name in the same textbox or cell.

Comment: What, exactly, is the value in the cell?  Quick and dirty fix would be `name.getValue().includes('Miguel')` or `name.getValue().indexOf('Miguel') > -1`

Comment: You could do a regex of some sort, or check if that cell contains Miguel anywhere

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Taplar. The value in the cell is always the name of the responsible for any project. There are max. 3 names in each project and I want to send my projects to another sheet automatically.

Comment: I wasn't actually asking what it contains, programatically.  I was wanting to know an example of an actual value.

Comment: Please add some sample data input and the correspondin expected results.

Answer (score 0):

### You need to use the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events) `user`

- This will return you the [active user](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getactiveuser)
- Mind that due to [restricitons of simple triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions) you will need to [set up an installable onEdit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) by going on `Edit > Current project's triggers`

**Sample code snippet to bind to an installable trigger:**

```js
function InstallableEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var r = e.range;
  var s = r.getSheet();
  var user = e.user;
  if(user == "EMAIL_OF_THE_USER" && s.getName() == "Job Planning" && r.getColumn() == 4 && r.getValue() == "Complete and Sent") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Complete and Sent");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 2, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
  } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This looks like an onEdit() function which could be written something like this and requires the event object of the onEdit() simple trigger.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const s=e.range.getSheet();
  if(s.getName() == "Job Planning" && e.range.columnStart==4 && e.value=="Complete and Sent") {
    var targetSheet = e.source.getSheetByName("Complete and Sent");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 2, 1);
    s.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,s.getLastColumn).moveTo(target);
  } 
}
```

[onEdit event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)